# php mvc модель и связь один ко многим

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Интересует такой вопрос, например, есть две таблицы в базе данных

Таблица news

```
id  title       cat_id
1   Новость 1      3
2   Новость 2      2
3   Новость 3      1
```

Таблица categories

```
id  title
1   Категория 1
2   Категория 2
3   Категория 3
```

А также создано две модели для работы со своими таблицами данных (news_model и categories_model).
В итоге получается (в качестве примера приведу вывод последних новостей), что я в контроллере сначала обращаюсь к методу модели news_model, который возвращает массив с последними 10 новостями. После чего В КОНТРОЛЛЕРЕ прохожусь в цикле по полученному массиву и формирую массив из идентификаторов категорий. После чего обращаюсь к методу модели categories_model, который возвращает массив категории по их идентификаторам. После этого в контроллере формирую массив с данными для вывода ($result = [ [news] => [....] , [categories] => [.... ] ]) и отдаю эти данные в вид. В итоге он (вид) возвращает HTML код в контроллер, а тот в свою очередь отображает этот код пользователю.

Так вот. Вопрос в следующем. Как правильно это организовать. Мне кажется, что в контроллере не правильно проходиться в цикле по данным, а как это сделать правильно я не знаю.

Comment: Интересно, когда перестанут плодить тему за темой про `MVC` их тут прсото уже не реальное количество...

Comment: На чистом php вы хотите сделать связь? Не проще ли взять базу (фреймворк) и сделать уже всё по-человечески? Как пример можно использовать Laravel. Не тратьте время на написание своего велосипеда, всё равно вы прийдёте к тому, что необходимо использовать фреймворк.